# MARKER constant override Symfony2 error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, I have a categories entity set up with a `parent_id` being self-references. But for some reason when I save the entry in the form I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant MARKER from interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy in /var/www/html/project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/Proxy.php on line 30
```

Can't figure out what it might be. I set the relationship up according to the Doctrine documentation.

```
/**
 * Set parent
 *
 * @param string $parent
 * @return Category
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parent
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this issue is related with the snippet of code you provided ?

Comment: It's the only change I made before it started throwing an error so I can't imagine it being anything else.

Comment: maybe `setParent()` and `getParent()` are reserved method?

Comment: Nope. Tried changing it to a different name and it still throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in `Doctrine-bundle`. Updating it to version 1.2.* (and subsequently updating dependent packages) fixed the issue.

Comment: I experienced the same error message, although `Doctrine-Bundle` is already on `1.2.*`. But after restarting the web server, everything worked fine again. I guess it was an error in the opcode cache (I am using APC).

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the exact same problem today after doing a change that should not affect Doctrine in any way (I altered a *Twig*  template). After some time I realized that since it's a strange compile error on a strange moment, probably `restarting php-fpm` would do the trick. And it did.

Maybe restarting Apache does the same if you're on `mod_php`.

Comment: Okay, this one did not really help me out. I had to restart php-fpm after every request to the server. What permanently solved the issue, was upgrading php from 5.4.17-1 to 5.4.17-2 (CentOS remi rpm releases). Unfortunately I don't know for sure whether upgrading php-fpm or upgrading apc solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the server solved the problem for me.

(Using PHP 5.4.15, APC 3.1.13, Apache2.4.4, Doctrine2.2)

Comment: Most likely it is caused by APC cache. Fixed to me with apache restart

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem with php-fpm 5.4.19, nginx 1.4 and APC 3.1.15 (?) on Centos6-64. As Mark was also mentioning, the use of the Remi repository which I used as well. It seems like the 3.1.15 isn't officially released yet. There isn't even a tag for it on the pecl page! It looks like Remi was trying to fix something to get it work and named it 3.1.15, but can't figure out exactly what it was that he was trying to fix.

Anyway I yum removed the package and installed the current release with the pecl command (now @ 3.1.13), which resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that APC is dead, unmaintained, no stable version exists for PHP 5.4 (or greater).

I recommend you to switch to:

- opcache (php-pecl-zendopcache) for opcode cache
- APCu (php-pecl-apcu) for user data cache (which provides the same API than the old APC, without opcode cache)