# I'm getting fatal error after including SonataMediaBundle's form templates

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I've configured SonataMediaBundle, added relation to Media in my Entity. Admin for entity works fine until I add this snippet from docs:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            # other files
            - 'SonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig'
```

After that all I get is this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant MARKER from interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to make sonata_media_type work with its widget template?

Comment: Can you post your complete config file as well as your entity ?

Comment: The problem was in APC cache. I managed to disable it and things went better:)

I found anwer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097973/marker-constant-override-symfony2-error#answer-16120364

Answer (score 0):

googling for somedays for a similar error I came up with the conclusion that is has nothing to do with your code, but is some kind of strange bug in environment, more likely in APC.

Check this post if you are using amazon server: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=508800

After I did that upgrade the problem solved. I'm still waiting to see if it comes out again, because it was not a permanet error, and after each apache reload/restart it went away for a while...

Other op-caches may solve the problem without loosing performance.